# Error: operand type mismatch for `pop'

Tags: ассемблер, gnu

Всем привет, начал изучать ассемблер GAZ (GNU), и при написания банального `Hello World` Столкнулся с проблемой, не не пойму в чем дело

```
.data 
    msg:
    .string "Hello World\n"     // string
.global main 
main:
    push $msg 
    call printf 
    pop % eax 
    xor % eax, %eax 
    ret
```

Ошибка

```
 Error: operand type mismatch for `pop'
```

Answer (score 0):

В 64-х битном коде нельзя пушить 32-х битные регистры.

```
POP RAX
```